# How can I format the double digits rows of a pyramid in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good day or night! I have an issue where the formatting of the bottom row of my number pyramid differs from the other rows. While I do know it's because of the extra digit, I do not know how I should go about fixing it.

I tried using format() and the repetition operator to fix it but nothing worked. Can someone offer me another solution?

```
pyramid_height = int(input("Enter the height you want your pyramid to be!\n"))
row = 0
col = 0
row_len = 0
digit_len = len(str(pyramid_height))
#print(digit_len)
print("Printing pyramid:")
for row in range(1, pyramid_height+1): #for each row (starts at 0) in the range of 1- 3+1 (4)
    row_len +=row
    if (digit_len == 1):
        for col in range(1, pyramid_height-row+1): #Creates pyramid cols
            print(end = ' '*2) #Go through each col you want to make and put the nums in their place
            for col in range(row, 0, -1): #As row++, it controls the spacing between the nums 
                print(col, end = ' ')
            for col in range(2, row+1):
                print(col, end = ' ')
            print("")
    elif (digit_len == 2):
            for col in range(1, pyramid_height-row+1): 
                print(end = ' '*2)
            for col in range(row, 0, -1):
               print(format(col, "1d"), end = ' ')#-------------Affects the left side of the pyramid
            for col in range(2, row+1): #Controls the amount and formating of the top of the pyramid
                print(format(col, "1d"), end = ' ')
                #print(" ", end = '')#--------------------Affects the right side of the pyramid
            print(" " * len(str(col)))
```

Comment: Can you please show the pyramid itself? It would really help me to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

You failed to adapt your 2-digit output to a 2-digit width: all of your formats are very specifically set for a single column:

```
format(col, "1d")
```

How did you expect that to give you the proper spacing?

You have to handle *all* of your formatting for the additional width: field specifications, inserted white-space strings, etc.

```
elif (digit_len == 2):
        for col in range(1, pyramid_height-row+1): 
            print(end = '  '*2)
        for col in range(row, 0, -1):
           print(format(col, "2d"), end = '  ')#-------------Affects the left side of the pyramid
        for col in range(2, row+1): #Controls the amount and formating of the top of the pyramid
            print(format(col, "2d"), end = '  ')
            #print(" ", end = '')#--------------------Affects the right side of the pyramid
        print(" " * len(str(col)))
```

Output for size 12:

```
Enter the height you want your pyramid to be!
12
Printing pyramid:
                                             1   
                                         2   1   2   
                                     3   2   1   2   3   
                                 4   3   2   1   2   3   4   
                             5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   
                         6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   
                     7   6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   
                 8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   
             9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
        10   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10    
    11  10   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11    
12  11  10   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
```